# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '900905 ' to data type int

Tags: sql

I have Below sp.

```
   ALTER procedure [dbo].[stpxxxx]


    @ID  int = null,
    @FKcomID int = null,
    @type int = 1

    as
    begin
    IF (@type = 1)

    BEGIN
   ----query A 
    SELECT     Member.PKID, Member.FKID, Person.ID, Member.FKID, Member.StartDate
    FROM         Member INNER JOIN
                          Person ON Member.FKID = Person.PKID 
    WHERE     (Person.ID = @ID)AND (Member.FKID = @FKcomID)

    end   

      ELSE
    BEGIN
     ----query B 
    SELECT     pre.PKID, pre.FKID, pre.FKPersonID 
    FROM         pre INNER JOIN
                          Person ON pre.FKID = person.PKID
    WHERE     (Person.ID = @ID) AND (pre.FKID = @FKcomID)


    end
```

if (@type = 1) there was a error

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '900905 ' to data type int.
```

If I swap the query A and B it aslo gettion erroe with  IF (@type = 1).
what is wrong with my Sp.

Comment: trim the trailing space springs to mind...Lesson here is read errors carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be an issue with whitespace.

Try this:

```
LTRIM(RTRIM())
```

on the offending value.

Comment: I added- IF (LTRIM(RTRIM(@type)) = 1) . but same error

Answer (score 2):

If you do an `LTRIM(RTRIM())` on the value, it will work; there is a space causing the issue.